# Is it possible to use libertine on an Aquaris E4.5 yet?

Tags: xorg, ubuntu-touch, emulation, libertine

Libertine is a software for ubuntu touch devices, which acts as a container for legacy x-apps to make them running on your device. Thete are videos and instructions of people, who got libertine running on their Meizu devices. But is it possible to use libertine on an Aquaris E4.5 yet?

Comment: Can't answer my question now. I'll do it later. I say it shortly: Yes, it is. Follow the instructions of the several websites and feel free to install x-apps.

Answer (score 0):

Official answer: yes.  Practical answer: not until OTA-12.

Comment: More practical answer: with no external display support, and the quite limiting hardware of the E4.5, while possible to use libertine to run X apps, it's not going to be a fulfilling experience.